# AngularJS Directive Binding link: has no access to scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive

I'm trying to write my first AngularJS Directive; it's basically a piece of code that blurps out a number of stars (badges) out of a maximum number of stars.

The link: function() code in the directive doesn't seem to have access to the scope variables passed in that are not static values (although the template code does).

Do I need to put the link: code elsewhere?

the html:

```
<span class="badge"><span sa-motes mote-count="character.attributes.stamina.value" mote-max="5" stat-name="character.attributes.stamina.name"></span> </span>
```

the mote-max="5" makes i, but the mote-count="character.attributes.stamina.value" doesn't. (shows up as null in the scope

*The character.... data is loaded in the controller for this partial.*

The directive:

```
sistemaDirectives.directive('saMotes', function() {
      return {
    restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            moteCount: '=',
            moteMax: '=',
            statName: '@'
        },
    template: '<span ng-repeat="mote in motes" class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate" ng-class="{\'mote-empty\':$index>moteCount+1}"> </span>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl ) {
            scope.motes = [];           
            for (var i = 0; i< scope.moteMax; i++) {
                scope.motes.push( i );
            }}}});
```

I tried this inline code in my view and it worked:

```
<span class="badge">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate" ng-repeat="i in  getNumber(character.attributes.strength.value) track by $index"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate mote-empty" ng-repeat="i in  getNumber(character.attributes.strength.max - character.attributes.strength.value) track by $index">
</span></span>
```

the getNum function just creates an array (in the controller):

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

Help?

Comment: Is it intentional that the anonymous function under `link` in the directive has a parameter of `scope` and not `$scope`?

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy yes, the parameters to the link function are not injected, like they are for the controller

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: It's my understanding that link: is passed a particular scope, and should not use $scope - I'm copying examples from the angularjs site.

Comment: Except that if the scope variable is passed in as a literal, e.g. : 
    mote-count="5"
 as opposed to an object evaluation,like 
    mote-count="myobject.property"
then mote-count *is* available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you say that scope.moteCount is not available in the link function, and it should be.
As long as character.attributes.stamina.value has a valid value.

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79ywZ/) that just uses alert to show the value of moteCount.

I just took your code and initiated the surrounding controller with

```
$scope.character = {attributes: {stamina: {value: 10, name: 'theName'}}};
```

UPDATE

Since you are fetching the values that are passed in to the directive asynchronously they are problably not ready when the link function in executed. Use a watch inside the link function to be notified when the data is ready

```
  scope.$watch('mouteCount',function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue !== oldValue){
      console.log({label:'watch', value: scope.mouteCount});
    }
  });
```

Comment: The character.attributes... etc. is being loaded by $http (from a local json file) in the controller. It *is* being evaluated in the template, but console.log and debugging show that in the link: function, it is undefined. If I pass in a string value into the scope (character.attributes.stamina.name, which is "Stamina"), in the link: function it is the string literal "character.attributes.stamina.name", but if I evaulate it in the partial it's part of - or in the template of the Directive! - it shows its value (which is "Stamina").

Comment: Hoooooly majoley! That was it! Thank you so much! :)

Followup Question: Should I be doing this somewhere else, like in a controller for the Directive? Or can I tell the Directive to wait until the data is loaded? I just don't want to have to do this everywhere in my code...

Comment: It's difficult to give a general answer to your question. There are a lot of articles about this subject like this one http://jensrantil.github.io/refreshable-angularjs-service.html